# I can't play videos on Facebook and other websites using my Ubuntu 18.04 Firefox

Tags: 18.04, firefox, video

I have an Issue here I'm installed Ubuntu 18.04 and now as a Normal human I use Facebook but Videos didn't play with me.

I tried to search and find any solution but I didn't find anything that worked with me. What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Firefox will use FFmpeg libraries for some video playback and this could be your issue. Try Chromium, if you are not willing to install FFmpeg, as it does not have this limitation...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has changed a lot, HMTL5 is now set by default

Did you try to add the libavcodec57 to play H264 or MP3?

Try the following :

1. Close your browser
2. Open the Terminal
3. Copy and past this command :

**$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec**

After this install the H264 is set, now restart your browser

Comment: Thanks ,, I find another solution for this issue i run 
$ sudo apt-get update and then $sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras and it's works

Comment: @AhmedSalama worked $sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu 20 as well